# What does "the repository <repository name> does not have a release file" mean?

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get update`, but there are errors that I don't understand:

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

What does this mean, and how can I resolve it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because there is no release for the version of Ubuntu that you are running. The simplest way to resolve this would be to remove the outdated repositories from the updates, at least temporarily.

To do this:

1. Open your "Software & Updates" application
2. Go to the "Other Software" tab
   [image: Software & Updates - Other Software]
3. Remove the repositories that do not have a release:

   - Freshlight
   - Grub Customizer
   - Super Boot Manager
   - UGet
4. Press [Close]

The system will update the repositories that it reads and then you should be good to go. If, in the future, there are updates to these repositories to make them compatible with your version of Ubuntu, simply check the boxes and update again.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like other operating systems, all apps from older OS are not directly compatible with the updated version. The developer of the app needs to specifically update his app when a newer version of Ubuntu is released. Hence you are not getting this error on the newer version of Ubuntu. Probably the developer of the app is no longer maintaining it.